# Where is tftp efi shell command?

Tags: shell, uefi, tftp

Cannot find tftp command in  [shell.efi](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/raw/master/ShellBinPkg/UefiShell/X64/Shell.efi) app from Tianocore.

When type tftp, got 'tftp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file. Help also doesn't know about it.

I looked at sources and found it is implemented in DynamicCommand directory. Maybe command must be loaded or activated somehow before using?

Edit: well, the only way i found to get tftp client working on Tianocore shell is building [ShellPkg from sources](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/master/ShellPkg). There is `DynamicCommand/TftpDynamicCommand` subdirectory contains tftp application. It will produce tftp.efi on package building finished. "Manual" can be found [here](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/ShellPkg/DynamicCommand/TftpDynamicCommand/Tftp.uni). Still dont understand how to make shell with built-in tftp command and why Tianocore maintainers do not include procompiled tftp.efi in ShellBinPkg for example.

Answer (score 0):

[How to Run OVMF](https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/How-to-run-OVMF) article contain information on how to get pre-built OVMF images:

> Pre-built images are available at https://www.kraxel.org/repos/
>
> - These images are automatically built and track the latest OVMF code in the EDK II tree.
> - Some of these builds include a seabios CSM and can boot non-UEFI “legacy” operating systems. Note: seabios is GPLv3 licensed)
> - If your OS doesn’t work with RPM repositories, then you can manually download and decompress the RPM files under jenkins/edk2

You can find the latest OVMF RPM packages at [kraxel repository](https://www.kraxel.org/repos/). They contain the latest firmware and `UefiShell.iso` to boot. You will find `tftp` command you need and other cool stuff there.